# How to use dummy variable in lm() as dependent variable?

Tags: r, linear-regression, mean, lm, dummy-variable

I imported two csv files, which include the same variables at two different times. Then I managed to generate a new third csv file with the function rbind(). I tried to create a linear regression with the lm() function, whereas the time is used as a dummy variable. The other variables are numeric, I changed them from categorized to numeric. The output shows some variables as numeric and others categorized, which is suspect to me. I would like to take the mean of the variables and plot them against the dummy variable, where I always get an Error that the variable lengths are different.

I already tried the glm() function and took the mean of each variable. I also defined the variables as numeric.

```
gh_old_small_short <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, sep=";")
gh_new_small_short <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, sep=";")
```

```
ghold <- rbind(gh_old_small_short, gh_new_small_short,  fill=T)
names(gh_new_small_short) <- names(gh_old_small_short)
```

```
model1 <- lm(formula = dummy ~ GovernmentOfficials + OfficeOfPresidency + MembersOfParliament + Age +
            Police + TaxOfficials + JudgesAndMagistrates + FightingCorruption, data=ghold, na.rm=T)
summary(model1)
```

I expect a linear regression table that includes each variable in total and not each answer-option individually, because I reconstructed the variables as numeric.

Comment: There is no argument `fill` to `rbind`. What do you mean by it?

Comment: It fills missing columns with NA. When the code is used without fill=T, the outcome is the same.